# Root Hook Plugin to Run Before All Tests with Mocha and Playwright

Tags: vue.js, automated-tests, vue-test-utils, playwright

I've hooked up some automated tests for my Vuejs project by adding [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-e2e-playwright) to my project.

The Vuejs app was created using the vue-cli.

It all works fine and Playwright seems to be a very powerful automation library.

So I'm trying to write a Mocha root hook plugin which runs once before all of the tests. That looks something like this:

**hooks.js**

```
const playwright = require("playwright");

export const mochaHooks = {
  beforeAll() {
    const browser = await playwright["chromium"].launch({
      headless: false
    });

    const context = await browser.newContext();

    await page.goto("https://localhost:44392/");

    await page.fill("#Username", "demokitchenadmin");
    await page.fill("#Password", "Test1234)");

    await page.click("button.btn-primary");

    await context.storageState({ path: 'state.json' });

    await page.close();
    await context.close();
    await browser.close();
  }
};
```

I'm not sure how to integrate this with my Vuejs project.
I have tried to add the `--require` flag ([doco](https://mochajs.org/#root-hook-plugins)) so that the test command looks like this (in `package.json`):

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e --require './tests/e2e/hooks.js",
},
```

Unfortunately, this does not successfully run the code in that `hooks.js` file.

Can anybody nudge me in the right direction.
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. So I was close.
I had to use the CommonJS syntax.
I think I need to keep working on this,as I want to get it working in Typescript.

In any case, for any others looking to solve this problem, I changed my **hooks.js** file as follows:

```
const playwright = require("playwright");


exports.mochaHooks = {
  async beforeAll() {

    const browser1 = await playwright["chromium"].launch({
      headless: false
      //devtools: true
    });

    const context1 = await browser1.newContext();
    const page = await context1.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://localhost:44392/account/login");


    await page.fill("#Username", "demokitchenadmin");
    await page.fill("#Password", "Test1234)");

    await page.click("button.btn-primary");

    await context1.storageState({ path: 'state.json' });

    await page.close();
    await context1.close();
    await browser1.close();
  }
};
```

And in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e -r ./tests/e2e/hooks",
},
```

This works and that authentication code ran once before all my tests.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, in order to make it clear to future readers that it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use global setup function (https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#global-setup-and-teardown) which can be defined in your playwright.config.ts.